# jQuery client side password verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication, client-side

first of all I'd like to say **I realise** it's not a secure method.
This is only for training purpose.

The algorhitm should be:

1. click on a div with id="login-bg"
2. app displays the banner
3. provide the code
4. if the code's ok set cookie and fade out the banner
5. if the code's not ok the div shakes (still remaining on the screen)
6. if you don't want to provide the code press 'cancel' and fade out the banner

Set cookie function (it works fine):

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['is_logged']))
        { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetPwd(c_name,value,expiredays){
            var exdate=new Date()
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
            document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+";path=/"+             ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString())
            }
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

**And here must be the problem with jQuery:**

```
<?php
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['is_logged']))
        { ?>
        <div id="login-bg">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Provide the code!</h2>
                <form id="check-form" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="password" name="code" placeholder="code" id="code" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="enjoy"/> 
                </form>
                <h3>And enjoy free access!</h3>
                <a id="cancel">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if( document.cookie.indexOf("is_logged") ===-1 ){
                $('#video').click(function(){
                    $("#login-bg").fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $('#cancel').click(function(){
                    $('#login-bg').fadeOut('slow');
                    //window.location = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/index";
                });
            }
            $("#submit").click(function (){
                var value = $('#code').val();
                var pass = 'test';
                if( value == test ){
                    SetCookie('is_logged','is_logged',365*10)
                    $("#login-bg").remove();
                }
                else { 
                    $('#login-bg').effect( "shake" );
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

In my opinion the value '#code' id not passed to jQuery from the form.
But I may be wrong.

Do you have any ideas. Could you make it work?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for deleting your question after I answer it! You're welcome....

Answer (score 2):

looks to be a problem here..

```
var value = $('#code').val();
var pass = 'test';
if( value == test ){
    SetCookie('is_logged','is_logged',365*10)
    $("#login-bg").remove();
}
```

this will not equate the way you want it to:

```
if( value == test )
```

I would suggest changing it to,

```
if( value == pass )
```

also change

```
$("#submit").click(
```

to

```
$("#enjoy").click(
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed. However, the system still does not behave as it should. When I click 'submit' the banner just disappears ( doesn't matter if the code is ok or not ).

I think the value is not passed because when I do a simple test there's any alert:

```
$("#submit").click(function (){
                var value = $('#code').val();
                var pass = 'test';
                alert(value);
                if( value == pass ){
                    SetCookie('is_logged','is_logged',365*10)
                    $("#login-bg").remove();
                }
                else { 
                    $('#login-bg').effect( "shake" );
                }
            });
```

Comment: acutally there is no element with id of 'submit' on the page so that 'click' function will never trigger! Change it to $("#enjoy").click(.... and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your click handler for the submit was not correct and at the password check you've missed the quotes 'test'. (As the others already answered.)

Below is the demo of your code and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1fubrwky/). It uses the jQuery cookie plugin for the cookies, but your PHP cookies will work too. I have just no backend for the demo.

Sorry, it's not working on SO because of insecure operation, probably the cookies are not allowed here. But at jsFiddle it is working.

Also don't remove the login div with `$("#login-bg").remove();` because it will be removed from DOM and you can show it again to the user. It's better to only hide it.

```js
// if(!isset($_COOKIE['is_logged']))
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$.cookie('is_logged')) {
        console.log('not logged in, show form');
        //document.cookie.indexOf("is_logged") === -1) {
        //$('#video').click(function () {
        //$('#code').val(''); // clear input
        $("#login-bg").fadeIn('slow');
        //});
        $('#cancel').click(function () {
            $('#login-bg').fadeOut('slow');
            //window.location = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/index";
        });
    } else {
        $('#mainContent').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    
    $('#logout').click(function () {
        console.log('hide clicked');
        $('#code').val(''); // clear input
        $('#mainContent').hide();
        $("#login-bg").fadeIn('slow');
        $.removeCookie('is_logged');
    });

    $("#check-form").on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#code').val();
        var pass = 'test';
        if (value == pass) { // 'test') {
            //SetCookie('is_logged', 'is_logged', 365 * 10)
            $.cookie('is_logged', 'true', {
                expires: 7
            });
            $('#mainContent').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#login-bg").hide(); // don't remove the login section
        } else {
            $('#login-bg').effect("shake");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#login-bg {
    display: none;
}
#mainContent {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<div id="login-bg">
    <div class="content">
         <h2>Provide the code!</h2>

        <form id="check-form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="password" name="code" placeholder="code" id="code" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="enjoy" />
        </form>
         <h3>And enjoy free access!</h3>
 <a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
    <strong>Login succeeded!</strong> Shown after login!! 
    <a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>

</div>
```